# Upload Google Drive API Retrofit 2

Tags: android, api, upload, retrofit2

**Here is the interface for Retrofit2:**

```
public interface OAuthServerIntf {

....
@POST("upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
@Multipart
Call<JsonObject> uploadFileMutil(
        @Header("Authorization") String authToken,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part metaPart,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part dataPart);

}
```

**That's where I call:**

```
public void onActivityResult(...) {
   ....
 MultipartBody.Part filePart = 
    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileBody);
 Call<JsonObject> request =  
    server.uploadFileMutil(oauthToken.getAccessToken(),filePart);
 request.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>(){...});

}
```

**oauthToken.getAccessToken()**-accesstoken

**MultipartBody.Part filePart** - file that I want to send to the server

In general, how to conduct an inquiry and that these 2 parameters for **metaPart** and **dataPart**?

Read that **token** need to bring to the **Bearer** type, how to do it ???

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you found the answer. still show some code in below, and hope this help someone.

```
val contentType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
val content = "{\"name\": \"" + srcFile.name + "\"}"
val metaPart = MultipartBody.Part.create(RequestBody.create(contentType, content))
val dataPart = MultipartBody.Part.create(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), srcFile))
val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)

mDriveApi.uploadFile(headers, metaPart, dataPart)
```